# Regex on List Comprehension Not Producing List But List of Lists Instead

Tags: python, list, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to clean a table scraped from a website.

I have two questions:

1. I'm not sure why my code below is producing a list of lists instead of just one list
2. I'm scraping each column into an individual list and then converting them into a dataframe. Is it a good practice to do the data cleaning in the list or do I do the cleaning *after* they're converted into a dataframe?

```
doc_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='docflow.list_DocFlowList']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]")

doc_name_cleaned = [re.findall(r'\d+',i.text) for i in doc_name]
```

Comment: What do you think `re.findall` returns?

Comment: re.findall returns a list

Comment: Thank you user2357112 for asking this pertinent question! I can't believe I didn't think of that. I must remember to think of your question each time I'm stuck at a code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
doc_name_cleaned = [re.findall(r'\d+',i.text) for i in doc_name]
```

In the above line `re.findall()` function returns a list of matches(it can be more than one). Since you're matching pattern for a list of texts, the result is a list of lists.

You can try this, if you just want the text.

```
doc_name_cleaned = []
for i in doc_name:
    matches= re.findall(r'\d+',i.text)
    if matches:
        doc_name_cleaned.append(matches[0])
    else:
        doc_name_cleaned.append('')
```

Comment: Thank you! I was considering this `for` loop option but was wondering if a list comprehension would be a good way to do what I wanted to do. Guess not.